# iOS Simulator Not Rendering UI

Tags: ios, xib

I am baffled as to why my simulator is not rendering the user interface I built in the .xib file. Attached is an image of my .xib file and the simulator.  None of the button or labels appear. [image]  [image]

Comment: Did you forget to hook up the view property on your view controller in your xib?

Comment: You nailed it.  For some reason, the professor never covered that, and when he builds his UI, he just launched it without showing us to hook up the view property.  Is there a way this does it autmatically when you build the UI?

Comment: If you do "New File" in Xcode and create a view controller you have the option of checking a box that says "Create XIB File". When you check the box it will create the xib file and hook it to your view controllers view property automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the images, but it could also be related to the layout itself.  Unless you have defined constraints to locate your UI elements in the display, it may be as simple as the elements not being in the visual area of the emulated screen type!